# Why should I buy a car in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I get constant messages from fixers urging me to buy a car.

Yet I wonder: Why should and would I invest money in them? They are not cheap, and apparently, [I can't customize them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379311/can-you-customize-your-car-in-cyberpunk-2077).

> And through  progressing the story within my Nomad playthrough, I unlocked two bikes and two cars very early and they all seem pretty decent.
>  The Archer Hella EC-D I360 was shortly damaged but repaired early in the Delamain quest line. After Jackie's funeral I got his bike from his mother. As a Nomad, my old car got activated allowing me to buy it cheap for 100 Eurodollars from Lana. And during Panam's sidequest I got Scorpion's bike.

Is this merely a money sink to allow me to buy a fancy car for bragging rights?

Or are there some quests or races attached once I buy some of them?

Comment: FWIW, playing corpo, there's a point in the story where you lose your car and you cannot claim another to be called. You have to buy as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JeffMercado that event occurs regardless of backstory but you should get Jackie's bike around the same time. I suspect whether you get Jackie's bike might depend on whether you return him to Vik or not.

Comment: @kalina, ah crud, I didn't get the opportunity to. I had him wait for me when things went down. That would explain it.

Comment: @JeffMercado You should still get your starting car, the Archer Hella EC-D I360, back early in the Delamain quest line after you reported the damage.

Comment: @k0pernikus, ok, I have a quest going back to Delamain HQ which I haven't done yet, got sidetracked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no benefit other than having an additional choice to ride around in Night City.

There is a car racing quest with Claire from Afterlife, but you can always choose to pick her ride instead, and in one of the races you are even forced to.

Comment: Car ownership **is** required for one achievement, though -- Autojock!

Answer (score 6):

Many of the cars you can buy are better (faster, more durable, better handling) than the ones you get for free.

Every vehicle in Night City is a unique mix in its characteristics, and many are substantially more or less pleasant to drive than others. As for not being able to customize your ride... you’re looking at this the wrong way. Buying a preem new set of wheels *is* how you customize your ride. No, there’s no paint shop. But with literally dozens of rides to buy or find, you’re sure to find one that suits your style.

Comment: Yeah there are definitely many vehicles that drive far better. Personal favourite is the Coyote.

Comment: I get your intent, still to say that "buying new is how you customize" is a weird phrasing.